# Downloading Ubuntu, Removing wrecked OS and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu

I downloaded Xubuntu debian OS when I got my Lenovo laptop many years ago by booting from a USB and following a tutorial. Throughout the years I've wrecked my OS from my ignorance in deleting files that programs like ClamTK flagged as viruses and malware. A bunch of little things malfunction like volume controls, I can't send files to the Recycling Bin via the dropdown menus, I can't view files to upload from my desktop, etc...

I'm wondering how I can remove Windows 10 altogether, then USB boot a regular non-debian Ubuntu (which I think is more accessible for my knowledge of computers and interface friendly) without bricking my laptop.
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, you can follow these steps, depending on what Operating System you are currently using:

Ubuntu: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Windows: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Once you've created the USB drive, boot from it and run the Ubuntu installer. When you're prompted for "Installation Type" select "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu". This will remove everything on your hard disk, including all files so make sure you've backed everything up.

Just as a note, there's no such thing as non-Debian Ubuntu - Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the response!